# How do I prevent getting nil interface elements while using custom cell in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

There are many, many questions on this site and others addressing the issue of getting a `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` from trying to set an interface element in a custom table view cell.

***How can I prevent the interface elements from being nil when it's time to set them?***

I've done my homework and checked out the answers to these related questions.

- *I've made sure I don't register the class in the viewDidLoad, as I'm using a UITableViewController.*
- *The UITableViewController is referenced properly in the Main.storyboard file.*
- *The cells in the UITableViewController are given the proper reuseIdentifier and class.*
- *My dequeueReusableCell call to the tableView has the proper identifier, matching the one in the storyboard.*
- *I've broken the nib's outlets and reconnected them.*

**I'm setting up a UITableViewController, "FindTableViewController."**

```
class FindTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var services = Fetch().getServices()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    /*Sections & rows defined here*/
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Monk", for:indexPath) as! Monk
        let service = services[indexPath.row]
        cell.set(service)
        return cell
    }
}
```

**In another file, I define the custom cell Monk.**

```
import UIKit

class Monk: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleImage: UIImageView!
    //other outlets defined here

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func set(_ service:Service) {
        if let imgv = self.titleImage  {
            imgv.image = service.image
        } else {
            print(self.titleImage)
        }
        self.titleLabel.text = service.title
        /*other elements set here*/
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that I did something really, *really* stupid.

I've set the custom class name to Monk, and also the cell identifier to Monk, because I didn't want that confusion to be the source of the issue and making the names different didn't solve the problem.

[image]

[image]

I've even printed the values in the Service object and they match what was expected.

```
if let imgv = self.titleImage  {
            imgv.image = service.image
        } else {
            print(self.titleImage)
        }
```

Prints "nil" and the error is thrown on the next line,

```
self.titleLabel.text = service.title
```

I also set the identifier and class of the nib to "Monk".

Comment: I don't see the titleLabel IBOutlet. Also do you reload only once the fetch has been completed? Or do you do it asynchronously?

Comment: @Jay I omitted the titleLabel IBOutlet to make the question shorter; The fetch thing wasn't it, I explicitly defined the variable and the same thing occurred. The problem isn't in the data being sent to the outlet, but the existence of the outlet itself. Great suggestions, though

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your checklist.  It sounds like you have a separate NIB for your custom cell (since you "broke the nib's outlets and reconnected them").  Yet you also wrote that "I don't register the class in viewDidLoad" because you are using a table view controller.  That would be a problem.

Comment: @ozzieozumo Wait... so not registering the nib is void only if you define your cell's elements within the UITableViewController itself?

Comment: Correct ... if you layout the cells in the storyboard (within the table view controller's prototype cells area), then you don't need to register a NIB because dequeue will create the cell's outlets based on the storyboard information.  Otherwise, if you are using a custom cell with custom NIB, then you need to register it so that dequeue knows how to instantiate a cell with outlets.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was totally the problem. If you want to copy that into an answer, I can accept it to make it more accessible for the community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something simple.

If you are using a custom NIB for your cell, then you do need to register it.

Something like this in viewDidLoad:

```
let myNib = UINib(nibName: "MonkCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(myNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Monk")
```

This is unnecessary if you choose to layout the cell directly in the storyboard for your view controller.